# Play more than one HTML 5 Audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

For some reason I cannot play more than one audio on my page. It did have an ID before and then I read somewhere on Stackoverflow that an ID is unique, so I changed it to have a class and now its not playing at all. But when it was getElementbyId only the one audio was playing and not all of them. Did I add the wrong code? Please help

I have this code here:

This is what it was before

```
<audio id="nyan" src="https://elysian.dijestdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Jessica_Roberts_Afrikaans_Corporate_SouthAfrican-sassa.mp3" preload="metadata" type="audio/mpeg"> 
     Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>

        <a class="btn" id="nyan-btn"></a>
```

Then I changed it to this

```
    <audio class="nyan" src="https://elysian.dijestdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Jessica_Roberts_Afrikaans_Corporate_SouthAfrican-sassa.mp3" preload="metadata" type="audio/mpeg"> 
     Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>

        <a class="btn" class="nyan-btn"></a>

<audio class="nyan" src="https://elysian.dijestdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Jessica_Roberts_Afrikaans_Corporate_SouthAfrican-sassa.mp3" preload="metadata" type="audio/mpeg"> 
         Your browser does not support the audio element. </audio>

            <a class="btn" class="nyan-btn"></a>
```

and Javascript

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
                       /*it was getElementById*/
            var nyan = document.getElementByClass("nyan");
            var nyanBtn = document.getElementByClass("nyan-btn");

            function playPause(song) {
                if (song.paused && song.currentTime >= 0 && !song.ended) {
                    song.play();
                } else {
                    song.pause();
                }
            }

            function reset(btn, song) {
                if (btn.classList.contains("playing")) {
                    btn.classList.toggle("playing");
                }
                song.pause();
                song.currentTime = 0;
            }

            function progress(btn, song) {
                console.log("PROGRESS");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var end = song.duration;
                    var current = song.currentTime;
                    var percent = current / (end / 100);
                    //check if song is at the end
                    if (current == end) {
                        reset(btn, song);
                    }
                    //set inset box shadow
                    btn.style.boxShadow =
                        "inset " +
                        btn.offsetWidth * (percent / 100) +
                        "px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)";
                    //call function again
                    progress(btn, song);
                }, 1000);
            }

            nyanBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                nyanBtn.classList.toggle("playing");
                playPause(nyan);
                progress(nyanBtn, nyan);
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: `getElementByClass` should be `getElementsByClassName`. Also, unlike `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of all elements with the specified class name so you'll need to loop through the list and add the event listeners to the buttons one by one. You will also have to restructure your functions that play the audio tags to go through the list and play the respective audio.

Comment: Hi @AndrewL64, thanks for your reply. I am not 100% sure how to write all of what you said in code.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Make one global button that play/pause all the audio tags at the same time or for each audio to have its own button?

Comment: I want each audio to have its own button. Because I would have to add an src to each button which will play different audios. At the moment only my first audio is playing. See here https://elysian.dijestdesigns.com/voices.html . Under the first artist only the first button is working the second, third and so forth arent working.